# how to get the available space left deterministically?

Tags: 14.04, grep, df, cut-command

When I use the cut command, everytime I get a different result which makes sense. So I wonder how to get the answer similar to this but consistent across different Ubuntu nodes?

```
ubuntu@ip:~/aws_script$ df -h / | grep '/dev'
/dev/xvda1       32G   21G  9.8G  68% /
ubuntu@ip:~/aws_script$ df -h / | grep '/dev' | cut -d' ' -f13
9.8G
```

I really don't care what command you would use if not `cut` as long as it gets the job done deterministically.

Comment: And why does the command you describe not suit your needs? Can you give an example where it does not work as intended?

Comment: it doesn't work on block of spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want second line, fourth column. So use awk for that:

```
$ df -h / | awk 'NR==2{print $4}'                                                                                                     
41G
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the available space on `/` with `df`, use:

```
df --output=avail -h / | grep -v ^Avail
```

#### How it works

`--output=avail` tells `df` to show just the available space.

`grep -v ^Avail` removes the header line.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is more powerfull than `cut`

```
df -h / |awk '/dev/{print $4}'
```

*Modified as requested by Serg*

Comment: Indeed awk is more powerful, but you're using `grep` here, which `awk` also can do. Just replace it with `df -h /  | awk '/dev/{print $4}'`